# python 2.7 get rid of double backslashes

Tags: python, string

I have list with one string element, see below

```
>>> s
['{\\"SrcIP\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"DstIP\\":\\"2.2.2.2\\",\\"DstPort\\":\\"80\\"}']
```

want to get rid of these '\\' and have dict instead:

```
{"SrcIP":"1.1.1.1","DstIP":"2.2.2.2","DstPort":"80"}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything you can show?

Comment: Hint: `string.replace('\\', '')`

Comment: Wrong question. The good question to ask (to yourself) is how you get that bogus string. It looks like you have partially decoded a json. Decode it correctly in first place and **this** problem will vanish...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like JSON object. You can load it to dict by using json package, but first to get rid of list and `\\` you can call `s[0].replace('\\', '')`

```
import json

my_dict = json.loads(s[0].replace('\\', ''))
```

Answer (score 1):

`s` is a list with one text item, you could get your desired output as follows:

```
import ast

s = ['{\\"SrcIP\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"DstIP\\":\\"2.2.2.2\\",\\"DstPort\\":\\"80\\"}']    
s_dict = ast.literal_eval(s[0].replace('\\', ''))

print s_dict
print s_dict['DstIP']
```

Giving you the following output:

```
{'SrcIP': '1.1.1.1', 'DstIP': '2.2.2.2', 'DstPort': '80'}
2.2.2.2
```

The Python function [`ast.litertal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html?highlight=ast%20literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) can be used to safely convert a string into a Python object, in this case a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import re
import ast
s = ['{\\"SrcIP\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"DstIP\\":\\"2.2.2.2\\",\\"DstPort\\":\\"80\\"}']
final_response = [ast.literal_eval(re.sub('\\\\', '', i)) for i in s][0]
```

Output:

```
{'SrcIP': '1.1.1.1', 'DstIP': '2.2.2.2', 'DstPort': '80'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use string replace method :

```
list_1=['{\\"SrcIP\\":\\"1.1.1.1\\",\\"DstIP\\":\\"2.2.2.2\\",\\"DstPort\\":\\"80\\"}']

for i in list_1:
    print(str(i).replace("\\",""))
```

Or you can do in one line:

```
print(str(list_1[0]).replace("\\",""))
```

output:

```
{"SrcIP":"1.1.1.1","DstIP":"2.2.2.2","DstPort":"80"}
```